# Why can't i use palette in netbeans 8.2?

Tags: netbeans

I don't really get the function of palette. (IDE Tools -> Palette)
Great tool, works nice in html and php, but in javascript it doesn't let me add anything nor does it show anything i could use.
It is locked or something?

Comment: I don't have NetBeans in this computer to check but I don't remember it came with items for JavaScript and creating them is [terribly complex](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-palette-api2.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't i use palette in netbeans 8.2?

You can, but probably not in the way that you want, assuming that you want to be able to use the **Palette** with JavaScript files, because:

- The **Palette** in NetBeans is primarily intended to be used for form development. It is not a general purpose tool for the automatic insertion of code.
- The content of the **Palette** window is context sensitive, and the categories available in the **Palette** at any time are directly tied to the type of the file currently open in the editor window. For example, the categories available in the **Palette** for **.html* files are different to those for **.jsf* files.
- Some file types, including JavaScript files (**.js*) and Java files (**.java*), have no associated categories. Although you can add a new category to the **Palette** for file types which already have one or more categories, you cannot create a new category in the **Palette** for a file type with no existing categories. This means that you cannot use the **Palette** with **.js* files.

While  NetBeans does not provide a category for *JavaScript* in the palette, you could add one yourself, but it would have to be tied to one of the file types that are already supported (e.g. **.html* or **.jsp*, but not **.js*). For example, you could:

- Create a new category named *JavaScript*, and add it to the Palette for **.html* files.
- Add an item named *alert* to that category which would allow you to insert `<script>alert('Hello world!');</script>` into **.html* files by double clicking that *alert* entry in the **Palette**.

> It is locked or something?

*"locked"* isn't the appropriate term since that would imply that you could somehow unlock the functionality, but you can't. At least not through the **Palette** user interface. NetBeans just doesn't support the use of the **Palette** with **.js* files.

The alternative to using the **Palette** for JavaScript files is to add your own code templates: **Tools > Options > Editor > Code Templates >** select **Language JavaScript >** click **New**